# "click" after a "fadeOut" fires immediately?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to run 3 jquery actions one after the other every 20 seconds.

I need to to:

1. first `fadeOut()` `#recent`
2. then when that has finished `click()` `.next`
3. then `fadeIn` `#recent()` again

Not sure it it makes any difference but `.next` is a child of `#recent`.

This is what I have so far:

```
$('#recent').fadeOut();
$('#recent .next').click();
$('#recent').fadeIn();
```

The problem is the click triggers before the fadeOut() has finished.

Thanks
C

Comment: And what is wrong with what you have so far?

Comment: The click triggers before the fadeOut() has finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `click` fires the simulated event *as soon as it is* invoked because it is *not* part of the animation event queue.

The easy was is to use the [on completed] callback for [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/):

```
$('#recent').fadeOut(function () {
  $('#recent .next').click()
}).fadeIn()
```

Note that the `fadeIn` animation *is* registered on the animation queue and thus "works as expected", even when not in the callback.

Happy coding.